# how to get arguments for sonar 5.6.4 in SonarJS

Tags: sonarjs

My sonar version is 5.6.4 which throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError at my code.

> org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.tree.expression.CallExpressionTree.argumentClause()Lorg/sonar/plugins/javascript/api/tree/expression/ArgumentListTree;

```
public void visitCallExpression(CallExpressionTree tree) {
    if (tree.callee() instanceof DotMemberExpressionTree){
      DotMemberExpressionTree dmTree = (DotMemberExpressionTree) tree.callee();
      System.out.println(tree);
      if (isLionGetProperty(dmTree) && tree.argumentClause().arguments().size() < 2) {
        addIssue(tree.callee(), MESSAGE);
      }
      super.visitCallExpression(tree);
    }
  }
```

My local plugin works fine which is based on Sonar 6.2. Where can I get some doc regarding an old version of SonarJS

Comment: what is the version of SonarJS in your old SonarQube instance?

Comment: It is 5.6.4 as I found at the footer of the page.

Comment: This is SonarQube version, you need to find the version of SonarJS installed on your SonarQube, you can find it in Update center or try to access `/deploy/plugins/index.txt` on your SQ instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `argumentClause` was added in SonarJS 3.0, you need to have at least this version of SonarJS installed to be able to use it. There is no documentation, you can find information in the [source repository](https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJs) or JIRA (e.g. `argumentClause` was added in [this ticket](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJS-691))

Comment: Thanks for the help across the ocean. I cannot find the index.txt. Yet I found  sonar-javascript-plugin-2.11.jar under /sonar/sonarqube-5.6.4/lib/bundled-plugins. So I guess it is 2.11. Is there a way to get argument size for this version? How much time does it usually cost to upgrade? ( I don't own the sonar instance. I may try and push the upgrade)

Comment: The upgrade should not be an issue. The latest supported version of SonarQube is 6.7, you can download from here https://www.sonarqube.org/  . See also upgrade notes in the documentation https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading